# No main() even if main() is there

Tags: java, swing, awt

I added this code to Netbeans and I am getting that file test1 doesn't contain `main()` function.

I have added `main()` function but still getting this error:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class test1 extends JFrame {

    // Window Vars //
    String title;
    int width;
    int height;

    // Mid Level componets //
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu file;
    JToolBar toolBar;
    JPanel map;
    JPanel sideBar;

    // Low Level componets //
    JMenuItem exit;

    JButton select;

    public test1(String title, int width, int height) {
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.makeInterface();
    }

    public void makeInterface() {
        // Setup JFrame
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
        this.setVisible(true);

        this.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                "debug, fillx, gap unrel rel",  // Layout
                "[grow, fill][fill]",         // Column
                "[fill][fill]"));       // Row
        this.makeMenu();
        this.addToolBars();
        this.makePanels();
        this.setupActionListeners();
    }

    public void makeMenu() {
        this.menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        this.file = new JMenu("File");
        this.file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        this.menuBar.add(file);

        this.exit = new JMenuItem("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_E);
        this.exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        this.file.add(exit);

        this.setJMenuBar(this.menuBar);
    }

    public void addToolBars() {
        this.toolBar = new JToolBar("Draggable");
        this.addToolBarButtons();
        this.add(toolBar, "span, height 20:35:50, wrap");
    }

    public void addToolBarButtons() {
        this.select = new JButton("Select");
        this.toolBar.add(select);
    }

    public void makePanels() {
        this.map = new JPanel();
        this.sideBar = new JPanel();

        this.add(map, "width 400:600:, flowy, growy");
        this.add(sideBar, "width 250:300:350, flowy, growy");
    }

    public void setupActionListeners() {
        this.exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new test1("r",400,400).setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Could someone please find out what the problem is?**

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN carefully?

Comment: @user3344508 please accept an answer if any of these have helped you.

Answer (score 12):

The correct signature of main is

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the `String[] args` parameter represents console arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You main needs as argument (String[] args)

Answer (score 1):

The required arguments are missing from the declaration of your main function.The correct syntax for main is  :

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some IDE like Eclipse. I recommend you to type ma and autocomplete it so that you'll never make any mistake.